# Call denied - how to call Phones with Sinch?

Tags: voip, sinch

I am new to Sinch and just trying out the PSTN example.

However, I can only place a call to the Mobile Number I used to register and nothing else.

Error:

```
Calling (OTHER NUMBER)
Answered at: Tue Dec 04 2018 09:22:46 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)
Ended: Tue Dec 04 2018 09:22:52 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)
Duration (s): 5.574
End cause: DENIED
```

Whereas this page tells that the new account can call any number:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to top-up account balance using Paypal or Credit Card and calls will be allowed. Apparently, the free $2 USD doesn't work.

Comment: this doesn't make any sense, yet it's the real reason